# How to change TextBlock.Text from settings Win8?

Tags: c#, text, windows-8, textblock

I have TextBlock on my MainPage and settings. I want to change text of this textblock dynamically. I have button in settings to confirm changes :

```
private async void OK_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  _main.ChangeTbText(Common.NewName);
}
```

Where Common.NewName - my new text;

```
public void ChangeTbText(string newName)
{
    UserTextBlock.Text = newName;
}
```

It works but I have to refresh page, I want to do it without refreshing.

EDIT:

Thanks for answers, I created something like that:

in settings:

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private async void OK_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PropertyChanged += _main.ChangeUserName;

            Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, new Windows.UI.Core.DispatchedHandler(() => OnPropertyChanged("Text"))); 
        }

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            _main.ChangeUser(Common.NewName);
        }
```

On Main Page:

```
public void ChangeUser(string Text)
        {
            UserTextBlock.Text = Text;
        }
```

While debugging this UserTextBlock.Text is set ok, but I still need to refresh page to see it .

Comment: Perhaps the following will do the trick: Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, new 
Windows.UI.Core.DispatchedHandler(() => { OnPropertyChanged("Text"); }));

Comment: Have you implemented the inotifychanged interface?

Comment: No, im not. I will try with this :)

Comment: @Lolek i think you have just started ..so just read about the dataBinding basics..it will help you..

Comment: Solution was to create static object of MainPage and use it in Settings.